# Cannot load font in Django for AMP page

Tags: html, css, django

On an AMP page I want to add a reference to my font in the styles tag.
Can we use static to do so?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Brands';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("{% static '/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot' %}");
  src: url("{% static '/webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot?#iefix' %}") format("embedded-opentype"), url("{% static '/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff2' %}") format("woff2"), url("{% static '/webfonts/fa-brands-400.woff' %}") format("woff"), url("{% static '/webfonts/fa-brands-400.ttf' %}") format("truetype"), url("{% static '/webfonts/fa-brands-400.svg#fontawesome' %}") format("svg"); }
```

In my body section this works fine for me.

```
<amp-img
    src="{% static '\located_in\picture.jpg' %}"
    width="16"
    height="9"
    layout="responsive"
    >
</amp-img>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error during template rendering
In template 
C:\users\frank\desktop\test_env\src\templates\fontawesome\fontawesome-all.css, error at line 2702
Invalid block tag on line 2702: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you access any file in your Django static directory, you need to load staticfiles with jinja2
Eg:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<amp-img src="{% static '\located_in\picture.jpg' %}" width="16" height="9" layout="responsive" > </amp-img>
```

Comment: Jinja is the default TL for Django

Comment: it's syntax is very close to Jinja2, and designed to be. [Refer here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/) It says "*Django’s template language is designed to strike a balance between power and ease. It’s designed to feel comfortable to those used to working with HTML. If you have any exposure to other text-based template languages, such as Smarty or Jinja2, you should feel right at home with Django’s templates.*". It is the default language enabled when using `django-admin startproject` and only will change if you do so manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `{% load staticfiles %}` in my file again even though it was in base.html

Comment: Yes, even though it is, `{% load static %}` is a tag specific to the template you are working on.